# Consulta para retornar seguidores de amigos

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Estou iniciando em SQL e estou com problema para fazer um `query` com múltiplas linhas retornadas. Estou criando um clone genérico do twitter.

> **Objetivo:** Retornar os usuários que são seguidos pelas pessoas que o
>   usuário logado segue e exibir como pessoas que talvez ele conheça,
>   excluindo ele mesmo e as pessoas que ele já segue.

**Tabelas**

```
CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `usuario` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
   `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   `foto` varchar(80) DEFAULT 'imagens/semfoto.png'
);

CREATE TABLE `usuarios_seguidores` (
   `id_usuario_seguidor` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `seguindo_id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `data_registro` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse comando abaixo retorna as pessoas que o usuário logado(`$id_usuario`) segue, porém isso seria só a primeira parte do retorno.

```
SELECT seguindo_id_usuario
  FROM usuarios AS u
  LEFT JOIN usuarios_seguidores AS us
    ON (us.id_usuario = u.id)
 WHERE id_usuario = $id_usuario;
```

Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Ninguém pode me ajudar? :-(